# Problems regarding UI text field instantiation with swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I need to add extra functionality to the swiftui TextField, and for that I added the following wrapper to my text fields:

```
struct TextFieldDynamicWidth: View {
    let title: String
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var isFirstResponder: Bool
    let onEditingChanged: (Bool) -> Void
    let onCommit: () -> Void

    @State private var textRect = CGRect()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text(text.isEmpty ? title : text).background(GlobalGeometryGetter(rect: $textRect)).layoutPriority(1).opacity(0)
            HStack {
                CustomOnbordTextField(text: $text, isFirstResponder: $isFirstResponder, textRect: $textRect)
                    .frame(width: textRect.width)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomOnbordTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding public var isFirstResponder: Bool
    @Binding public var text: String
    @Binding public var textRect: CGRect
    private var tempTextField = UITextField()

    private var configuration = { (_: UITextField) in }

    public init(text: Binding<String>, isFirstResponder: Binding<Bool>, textRect: Binding<CGRect>, configuration: @escaping (UITextField) -> Void = { _ in }) {
        self.configuration = configuration
        self._text = text
        self._isFirstResponder = isFirstResponder
        self._textRect = textRect
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let view = tempTextField
        view.placeholder = "0"
        view.font = UIFont(name: "EuclidCircularB-Regular", size: 70)
        view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        view.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.textViewDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        view.keyboardType = .numberPad
        view.frame.size.width = textRect.width
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        configuration(uiView)
        print("##### isFirstResponder -> \(isFirstResponder)")
        if isFirstResponder {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator($text, isFirstResponder: $isFirstResponder)
    }

    public class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var text: Binding<String>
        var isFirstResponder: Binding<Bool>

        init(_ text: Binding<String>, isFirstResponder: Binding<Bool>) {
            self.text = text
            self.isFirstResponder = isFirstResponder
        }

        @objc public func textViewDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
            print("##### textViewDidChange -> \(textField.text ?? "")")
            self.text.wrappedValue = textField.text ?? ""
        }

        public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            print("##### textFieldDidBeginEditing")
            self.isFirstResponder.wrappedValue = true
        }

        public func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            print("##### textFieldDidEndEditing")
            self.isFirstResponder.wrappedValue = false
        }

        public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I navigate to a different view and use this exact same code it does not create new instances methods of the textfield, even if I duplicate the code and change the name of these two structs to something like (TextFieldDynamicWidth111) and (CustomOnbordTextField111) the method `updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context)` stops responding...basically how do I make unique instances of this code or deinit the previous view so that the delegate method can work?

Comment: Create it in `makeUIView` (as named) not at init phase.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried that, still same problem.

Comment: This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).